# Spring Data JPA query method is not same with the hibernate generated query

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple springboot application where I just query to a User table. I created a repository IUserRepository where I create the query method that returns specific columns only (spring data projections)

User table

```
columns (indexes: id, lastName, age)
id
firstName
lastName
age
```

UserProjection

```
public interface UserProjection {

     Integer getId();
     String getFirstName();
}
```

IUserRepository

```
public interface IUserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{

     @Query("select u.id, u.firstName from user u where u.lastName = ?1")
     public List<UserProjection> findUserByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

but when I set the hibernate.show_sql=true in my application.properties the result from the hibernate generated query in the logs is

```
select user0_.id as id_01, user0_.firstName as firstName_01, user0_.lastName as lastName_01, user0_.age as age_01 from user0_ where user0_.lastName = ?
```

I was expecting to see only the id and firstname since I specified a projection for the return. My expected query should be

```
select user0_.id as id_01, user0_.firstName as firstName_01 from user0_ where user0_.lastName = ?
```

am I doing it wrong? or my understanding is just wrong? can some help me understand this scenario. TIA

Comment: I doubt you are looking at the same query. Your query method has an `@Query` so Spring Data doesn't do anything with the method name to generate a query on the fly.

Comment: it is the only query method I have in the application and I have searched that to turn on the sql logs for hibernate I just need to set true the hibernate.show_sql property which I did and it showed the generated query from hibernate. IDK if the generated query was the interpretation of the query method in the repository.

Comment: It isn't the generated query because you explicitly provided the query.Remove the `@Query` annotation from the method and try again. Also why should the id be in there? There should only be a last name. Hence my suspicion the query is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: I will try and get back to you after.

what do you mean by "why should the id be in there?"

Comment: Look at the query it has both an `id` and `lastname` in the where clause.

Comment: sorry I edited it now. It was just a typo